# New Account in Windows 8 not available on Start Screen

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have installed Windows 8 and am the administrator

I have added a new account for my partner using her hotmail address.

When I logout there are 2 users to choose from to log back in

However, when I restart the laptop, the first time there is only my account available to log in with. And only once I have logged in, then logged out again, are the two account options available again

How can I make both available on the start up screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has your partner signed in yet with her Windows Live ID? The account is only set-up properly when the user signs in for the first time.

Also, if it only shows your username on the welcome screen, there may be a white arrow in a circle in the top left corner. Click that to show all the users on the computer.